# Mills' Constant Unpublished Extras

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

The brown paper used in the making of [Numberphile's video on Mills' Constant](http://youtube.com/numberphile) was recently [sold on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Numberphile-Brown-Paper-Mills-Constant-/380681839333?pt=UK_Collectables_Memorabila_RL&hash=item58a267e2e5). Here is an image of it, from the eBay listing,

[image: Image of Brown Paper used in the making of Mill's Constant]

The bottom two lines appear on the brown paper, but were not written in the video,

> $\lfloor {2 \omega n} \rfloor \hspace{10 mm} \omega = 1.9287800...$
>
> $2, \hspace{1 mm} 11, \hspace{1 mm} 1361, \hspace{1 mm} \text{[sic]} \hspace{1 mm} 252100887, \dots $

It is clear that the bottom line are the first Mill's Primes.

However, I cannot figure out what the second to bottom line is?

- **What is $\omega \approx 1.929$?**
- **What is $\lfloor {2 \omega n} \rfloor$?**

Comment: Not totally related but why on earth would anyone buy such a thing? I do not understand.

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Supporting a program they enjoy? Having a small piece of the show to frame? I dunno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value is cited in [Mathematical Constants by Stephen Finch](ftp://s208.math.msu.su/469000/dbcd69f8d83a96354dd49d21572c6432) on page 131 but called $c$.  It is another prime representing function giving primes for the floors of $2^c,2^{2^c},2^{2^{2^c}},\dots$.  It appears $2\omega n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ number of this series and the typography is not clear to me.

Comment: Am unable to open that link.

Answer (score 2):

Searching the [OEIS](https://oeis.org) yields $\omega=$ [A086238](https://oeis.org/A086238), which generates the primes [A016104](https://oeis.org/A016104) = 1, 3, 13, 16381, $2^{16382}-35411,\ldots.$ This is a less-efficient version of Mills' constant, essentially -- while Mills' primes grow doubly-exponentially, these primes grow tetrationally.

Answer (score 1):

[Wright's Forumla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formula_for_primes#Wright.27s_formula) is another prime generating formula similar to [Mills' Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MillsTheorem.html).

Wright's Formula is defined by the recurrence relation:

$$
        g_0 = \omega \\
    g_{n+1} = 2^{g_n}
$$
then
$ 
\lfloor g_n \rfloor
$
is prime for all $n \ge 1$ and
$\omega = 1.9287800...$ is the constant that apears above.

Comment: This is the correct answer